# SUM Progressive Groups of 3 Cells in a Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to SUM 3 cells in a row (sum(A1:C1)) and as I drag the formula to the right it should sum progressive groups of three cells; e.g. sum(D1:F1).  Please see bellow:

```
   A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    k    L
1  100  200  300  400  500  600  700  800  900  100  200  300
2  600  1500 2400 600
```

Cell A2 is showing the sum of cells A1:C1, and Cell B2 is showing sum of D1:F1.  I want to see how I can drag cell A2 to the right and have the results as above. Regular sum will shift cells 1 to the right and I want them to be shifted 3 to the right to get the correct results.

I need to use this formula to get sum of sales for each quarter.

Answer (score 2):

While the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) may seem a more likely candidate for this it is a *volatile* function that should be avoided if possible. A pair of [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)s can perform teh same operation with a little math.

In A2 use the formula,

```
=SUM(INDEX(1:1,(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*3+1):INDEX(1:1,(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*3+3))
```

Fill right as necessary.

[image: SUM an Offset with Index]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I tried to work with the offset function as well and it got me very confused.  But Thank you very much for your time and help, this is exactly what I needed.